# randomly generate a number in c++ but only certain multiples

Tags: algorithm, random

I'm trying to generate a random number to use as a coordinate in c++, the coordinate must be within range of 0-700, the coordinate generated, however, must be a multiple of 20 only,(0,20,40,60,80 etc) is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just multiply whatever number you got by 20 and you have your multiple of 20.

Comment: Hint: is there a trivial mapping of `0,1,2,3,4` to `0,20,40,60,80`?

Comment: @ tkausl I actually didn't even think of that, so simple. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your number has to be in range `[0;700]` and must be divisible by `20` you could just simply generate a random number within a range `[0;35]` (because 35*20 = 700) and multiply it by `20`.